# passing additional parameters to rsync using rsnapshot

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I have my backups being performed by rsnapshot, works well.

EXCEPT, on one of the jobs for the /home volume I'd like rsync to copy the sym-links as physical directory/files.  I believe the parameter is --copy-links for rsync but can't seem to find a way to pass it to rsync from rsnapshot.

Preferably I'd like to do this on a job by job basis. While it makes since for my /home tree it doesn't for /etc and /var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate config file for this host

```
cp /etc/rsnapshot.conf /etc/rsnapshot.link.conf
```

Only add the directories where you want the symlinks to be copies and remove all of the other backup definitions.

add:

```
rsync_long_args --copy-links
```

near the

```
cmd_rsync       /usr/bin/rsync
```

line. and invoke like:

```
rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot.link.conf daily
```

in cron.

Result:

```
[root@xxxxxxxxxxx /]# rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot.link.conf daily
/bin/cp -al /.backups/links/daily.0 /.backups/links/daily.1
/usr/bin/rsync -a --copy-links --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh \
root@xxxxxxx:/home/ /.backups/links/daily.0/xxxxxx/
```

Comment: Thank you!  I live give this a shot this evening and mark it if it works.

Comment: Worked! Thank You!  Only thing to note is the spacing "rsync_long_args" and "--copy-links" MUST be a space or rsnapshot will complain about it.

Comment: One other thing snapshot_root needs to be pointing to another destination or it will rotate the backups.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like

`backup  <source>      <dest>  +rsync_long_args=--copy-links`

in the backup section of the rsnapshot.conf file.